# Python ERROR: ('must be real number, not str',)

Tags: python, dataframe, geopandas

I have the below Python code to read files of different extensions into a geopandas dataframe and then convert that dataframe into a shapefile

```
        try:
            xyz_path = self.jobDict['xyz_key'][0]

            ## Get raw XYZ file
            print(str(datetime.now()) + ' get_object (start)')
            input_file = self.s3_client.get_object(Bucket=self.jobDict['bucket'], Key=xyz_path)
            print(str(datetime.now()) + ' get_object (end) : ' + xyz_path)

            file_extension = xyz_path.split(".")[-1]
            output_file = os.path.basename(xyz_path)[:-4]


            if file_extension in ("xyz", "asc"):
                df  = pd.read_table(io.BytesIO(input_file['Body'].read()), skiprows=2, sep=r'\,|\t', engine='python', names=['x', 'y', 'z'])
                df.columns = ["x", "y", "z"]

            elif file_extension in ("txt", "text", "csv"):
                df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(input_file['Body'].read()), sep='\,|\t')
                df.columns = ["x", "y", "z"]
                    

            gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=df.apply(lambda row: Point(row.x,row.y,row.z), axis=1))

            gdf.to_file(f"{output_file}.shp") 
            shapefile = f"{output_file}.shp"

            print("Shapefile Created!")
```

However, my xyz files are giving an error `ERROR: ('must be real number, not str',)` but they are numbers. The file contains no text - see below.

577669.82 564383.38 9.14

577670.70 564382.59 9.22

577671.65 564381.79 9.27

577673.03 564380.73 9.17

What's the issue?

Comment: you need to parse data into float/integer after you read it.

Comment: I tried adding ```df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)``` but I'm getting the same error

Comment: you provide the argument `sep=r'\,|\t'` to read_table. But are the columns separated by a tab or is that a space? you could try `sep="\s+"` to match on one or more spaces *or* tabs - that might help. But you can't just turn the string `"577669.82 564383.38 9.14"` into a number - you need to parse the file correctly or work with [pandas string methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#string-methods) to format the data correctly before it will be interpretable as a number. this isn't a pandas error ;) step through your code line by line to ensure you're doing what you intend.

Comment: also, a bit of unsolicited advice. it looks like this is all wrapped in a try/except block. a common thing for new programmers to do is to wrap all your code in a ton of error handling. I'd recommend stripping this out. if your code is raising an error, it's usually trying to tell you something. read this guide to understanding the [python traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) and write your code so that if there is an error, you'll find out exactly what's going wrong, rather than trying to magically handle it for yourself - that tends to result in really hard to debug problems.